# Obtener estado de switch en mainActivity Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

tengo dentro de mi mainActivty, un menu al que le setee un Switch de esta manera

activity_main_drawer.xml

```
<item
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_light"
                    app:actionLayout="@layout/menu_switch"
                    android:title="Modo"
                    />
```

Y dentro del menu_switch.xml

```
<Switch xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/nav_switch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    />
```

Como podria acceder al estado del switch(nav_switch) desde el activityMain?, para otorgar acciones en caso de que el switch fue checkeado o no. gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para obtener el estado de un Switch usa [OnCheckedChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton#setOnCheckedChangeListener(android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener)), define este listener a tu Switch y podrás obtener su estado:

```
 mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(object : CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener{
                override fun onCheckedChanged(switch: CompoundButton?, isChecked: Boolean) {

                  if(isChecked) {
                     //Encendido
                  } else {
                    //Apagado
                  }


                }
            })
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]